Is there a way to get value from Named Principal as string in APEX?
I have non-standard case where I need to generate an additional token to send in the request header. For that token I need API_KEY and API_SECRET which I have stored in Named Principals.
The way described in help or on the forums with the formula
 String API_KEY = '{!$Credential.MyTest_ExtCredentials.API_KEY}';

is not working as this formula is only resolved when added as header value and at exact moment when call is made.
I need to get this value before call is sent. Is that possible?

I do not believe you can, and believe that this is a deliberate security feature.

There's limited support for achieving the same outcome (build whatever header value) but without retrieval via formula functions: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_named_creds_formula_functions.htm&type=5 .
